# How to force exe file to run on Nvidia GPU on windows

Tags: c++, gpu, nvidia

I have a program written in `C++` language. My whole code contains only 3 files: a header file for my own class, a cpp file with code implementation for the class and a 3rd cpp file where I have the `main()` method.

I need to make very complicated calculations, and on a normal CPU my code takes about 3 months to complete the execution. That's why I tried to run the program on my Nvidia GPU. The code was developed on Visual Studio IDE and I made an EXE file.

This is what I tried to do:

1. Went to graphics settings -> Choose the relevant Exe file -> set the file for high performance with Nvidia card. This did Not work.
2. I open Nvidia Control Panel -> apps settings -> again, picked the relevant Exe file -> select Nvidia GPU for high performance. Also, no luck here.

Both ways failed, my code is running on my Intel GPU and not on my Nvidia card.

How can I force the execution of the Exe file to run on the Nvidia card?

Is three a way via the command line (or any other way) to make my C++ code to be compiled and run on my Nvidia GPU?

Comment: That's a strange desire. What makes you think that you can compile a program for Intel CPU and then transfer it to Nvidia CPU, where it magically gains high performance? That is not how things work.

Comment: Does your code supports dedicated GPU? If yes, which library you are using (vulkan, direct3d, etc). Try CUDA

Comment: I know this is doable on Linux with Python. When I check the performance of my laptop I clearly see that the code is running on Intel GPU. And no, I'm not using any library as my code is a simple C++ program.

Comment: Which API are you using to run code on the GPU? OpenGL, OpenCL, Vulkan, SYCL, Direct3D, OpenMP?

Comment: @PeterT I have a "simple" C++ code that prints to the console and do calculations. The code was compiled to an Exe via Visual Studio. I'm not using any of the things you said.

Comment: Which part of that "simple" code do you think is running on the Intel GPU and by what mechanism? Why do you think it's not just running on the CPU?

Comment: @PeterT I have CUDA installed, but I don't know how to work with this. Couldn't make my objects and functions to run on the Global kernel function. When I run my Exe and go the the laptop's performance I see a spike in the Intel GPU usage and not on Nvidia GPU which stays on 0 the entire time.

Comment: @TalAngel do you see the GPU-usage go up even if you hide/minimize the window of your program? Or is it just from drawing the text of your output?

Comment: @PeterT Yes - for the 1st option. But the GPU running is Intel and not Nvidia.

Comment: I don't think people can easily help you, if we don't know how the code runs on the GPU, are you sure you're not using something like openmp annotations or the parallel STL? Regular standard C++ doesn't automatically run on the GPU when just normally compiled with Visual studio

Comment: If it's just a simple C++ program not using any of the APIs listed by PeterT, then it runs on a CPU, not GPU. And you can't easily make it run on a GPU, without using one of the listed APIs.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Please guide me on what to do. Don't just say that it's possible, please explain why and how to do it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of the listed APIs except OpenGL, which isn't really suitable for computations (it's for drawing stuff).

Comment: @TalAngel this might give you a start. https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/

Comment: @TalAngel To answer your curosity, the code compiled for CPU cannot run in a GPU. GPUs have very limited instruction set, don't support exactly same operations/data-types as CPU and are completely a different thing. Usually, you write a program which starts on CPU, then pushes some workload to GPU, takes the result back and continues working on CPU.

Comment: Your problem is conceptual, exe's always run on top of an operating system, which is using a CPU. GPU functions are supported by way of an API like CUDA or OpenCL or Vulkan. You can also use GPGPU frameworks like C++AMP and boost.compute, or use optmized versions of Eigen and the like. But the gist of it is that you need to rewrite your entire program to be massively multi-threaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no easy and/or automatic way to compile general C++ code to be executed in a GPU. You have to use some specific API for GPU computing or implement the code in a way that some tool is able to automatically generate the code for a GPU.

The C++ APIs that I know for GPU programming are:

- CUDA: intended for NVIDIA GPUs only, relatively easy to use. Here you have a good introduction: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/even-easier-introduction-cuda/
- OpenCL: can be used for most of the GPUs in the market, but is not as easy to use as CUDA. An interesting feature of OpenCL is that the generated code can also run in CPU. An example here: https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/
- SYCL: a relatively recent API for heterogeneous programming built on top of OpenCL. SYCL highly simplifies the GPU programming, I found this interesting tutorial which shows how easy to use SYCL is: https://tech.io/playgrounds/48226/introduction-to-sycl/introduction-to-sycl-2

Unfortunately, you will need to rewrite some parts of your code if you want to use one of these options. I believe that SYCL will be the easier choice and the one that will require less modifications in the C++ code (I really encourage you to take a look at the tutorial, SYCL is pretty easy to use). Also, it seems that Visual Studio already supports SYCL: https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/platform-support/targeting-windows

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA offers a high performance C++ compiler that will generate code moving some of your workload onto the GPU.
This works best using C++17 parallel algorithm.

Likely - you have to re-write some your existing C++ code and then compile it using NVIDIA's C++ compiler.

Your code/algorithm must support some form of parallelism.

Here are some links with information about NVIDIA's HPC C++ compiler.

https://developer.nvidia.com/hpc-compilers

https://developer.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-hpc-sdk-downloads